# Show that $f:W \to W$ is diagonalized

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $f \in End(V)$, $\dim V=n$ and $W$ is $f$- invariant subspace of $V$ if $f:V \to V$
is diagonalized then show that $f:W \to W$ is as well.

My attempt:

Since $f$ is diagonalised then we can choose basis $B=\{v_1, …, v_n  \}$ of V  where $v_i$ are eigenvectors so we can choose such subset of $B$ that is basis of $W$ and then $W$ is diagonalized.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Maybe we can consider the induced mapping $\bar{f}:V/W \to V/W$ given by $\bar{v} \mapsto \bar{f(v)}$, which is well-defined since $W$ is $f$-invariant. You're proof is incorrect because a basis for $V$ doesn't need to contain a basis for $W$.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented, your reasoning is incorrect. One could try the following: let $\;m_W(x)\;,\;\;m_V(x)\;$ the minimal polynomials of $\;f|_W\;\;and\;\;f\;$ , resp.

Since $\;m_W(f)=m_V(f)=0\;$ (just look at both cases as a map on $\;V\;$ ),  we get that $\;m_W(x)\mid m_V(x)\;$ , and since $\;f\;$ is diagonalizable then $\;m_V(x)\;$ is a product of *different* linear factors, but then also $\;m_W(x)\;$ is , and we're done.